# How to use backreferences in oracle sqldeveloper find/replace

Tags: regex, sqldeveloper

How do you use backreferences when doing regular expression find/replace in Oracle SQLDeveloper?  `\n` doesn't work for me and neither does `$n`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jeff Smith, one of the developers of SQLDeveloper, [answered in his blog](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/08/oracle-sql-developer-4-quick-hit-search-and-replace/#comment-72865), that this bug is caused by JDeveloper 4.0.

> JDeveloper broke this when we went to version 4.0 and their new framework. I contacted the developer and logged the bug so that hopefully we can have it working as expected again in version 4.1

He filed the bug already to the JDeveloper team and hopes this bug will be fixed before version 4.1 of SQLDeveloper gets published.

**Update**

It's fixed in versions 4.1+.

Comment: I know that this is quite old but could you possibly quote the relevant parts from your link? This is in case it gets removed for any reason in the future.

Comment: Of course, added the information.